# My javascript functions are not returning a result

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the average of an array using spread operator, but my functions are not returning any result. Why?

```
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    console.log(...arr);
    let sum = (...arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    console.log(sum);

    avg = sum / (arr.length);
    console.log(avg);
```

Comment: You are never executing your `sum` function. Your `console.log` should tell you that very clearly

Comment: What is the output of your `console.log(sum)`? What does the output mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```js
function findAverage(...numbers) {
    // the formula for getting average is (sum/total)
    let sum = 0;
    numbers.forEach(number => {
        sum += number;
    });
    const total = numbers.length;
    const average = sum / total;
    return average;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
findAverage(...arr); // returns 3
// or
findAverage(1,2,3,4,5) // returns 3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the only answer so far that uses the spread correctly. Though you can improve it by using `reduce` for summing (don't forget the edge case!)

Answer (score 1):

You made the function to get the sum:

`let sum = (...arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);`

But you didn't actually apply it yet, so there is no result. To apply it:

`let totalSum = sum(...arr);`

Then, to calculate the average:

`let avg = totalSum / arr.length;`

Answer (score 1):

You are never calling your arrow function and you cannot divide a function by a number. Call your function to get a numeric value:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const sum = ((...arr) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))(...arr);
// ...
```

Since the function is immediately invoked, you might as well just drop it:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `sum` is a function, not a numeric value.

Please try:

```
let sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the average of an array using the spread operator and the reduce function. Here's a concise example:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
let avg = sum / arr.length;
console.log(avg);
```

In your code, the spread operator (`...arr`) is not needed for calculating the sum. The correct usage is demonstrated in the example above.